# Can't get ShouldDecompile configuration in DelegateDecompiler to work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, calculated-columns

I'm trying to get an auto decompile configuration for [DelegateDecompiler](https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler) to work, as shown here: http://daveaglick.com/posts/computed-properties-and-entity-framework
But it doesn't work :(

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the class that has a computed value.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Computed]
    public string Full { get { return First + " " + Last; } }
}
```

This is the configuration.

```
public class DelegateDecompilerConfiguration : DefaultConfiguration
{
    public override bool ShouldDecompile(MemberInfo memberInfo)
    {
        // Automatically decompile all NotMapped members
        return base.ShouldDecompile(memberInfo) || memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NotMappedAttribute), true).Length > 0;
    }
}
```

I also tried removing the `[NotMapped]` and then changed `typeof(NotMappedAttribute)` to `typeof(ComputedAttribute)` in the above configuration.

Then I register it like so

```
DelegateDecompiler.Configuration.Configure(new DelegateDecompilerConfiguration());
```

In Startup.cs. I also tried putting it directly into my action.

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    DelegateDecompiler.Configuration.Configure(new DelegateDecompilerConfiguration());

    var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var result = ctx.People.Where(x => x.Full.Contains("foo bar")).ToList();

    return View();
}
```

Neither work :(

If I put `.Decompile()` on the query then it works as expected. So the DelegateDecompiler is working, but not the configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you discovered in your GitHub issue, you always have to call `.Decompile()` within your LINQ query. The extra configuration just eliminates the need to decorate all of your computed properties with the `Computed` attribute, instead relying on the Entity Framework `NotMapped` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

As Dave says it requires `Decompile()`

So you don't have to remember to call it you can create a mapper extension that wraps what you are doing.

```
public static class MapperExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a list from automapper projection. Also wraps delegate decompiler to supprt Computed Domain properties
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TDestination"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="projectionExpression"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<TDestination>
        ToList<TDestination>(this IProjectionExpression projectionExpression)
    {
        return projectionExpression.To<TDestination>().Decompile().ToList();
    }
}
```